# Cannot Update 14.04 Server

Tags: updates, package-management

The update fails with the following error messages:

```
bob@Proliant-Server:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Error!

E: Encountered a section with no Package: header

E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en

E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I have run the following commands to no avail:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

I am getting desperate! Any suggestions would be appreciated!
TIA

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested in the possible duplicate question mentioned above did work. Thank you.

These terminal commands solved my problem:

First remove the Merge List by opening a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch) and run this command:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

Next, generate a new one by running a simple update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```